# Is it ok to post draft answers and make extensive edits?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I'm only referring to my own answer, here.  My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24409079/revisions) looks like a lot more editing than I really did, and some of my changes aren't visible.  I think part of the reason is I moved the paragraphs around as a final edit, but I did three or 4 edits in rapid succession, so they got rolled into one.

What got lost is in the bottom paragraphs, none of the edits there are highlighted.  For instance, this sentence is completely new in an edit:

> If it didn't stretch more than halfway down the side of the element, I would be more inclined to call it a "Left Control Menu"

And all of the words "Control" are from an edit.

Normally, I don't make such extreme edits after posting, did I break the revision viewer by editing too much too quickly?

Comment: There's a grace period for edits. If you make them within 5 minutes(?) of posting, they're considered part of the original post.

Comment: @Wooble That would make sense, my re-ordering of paragraphs is what all the highlighting is about then, that was the last thing I did.

Comment: Some history on the [Fastest Gun in the West problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) and [Why do we reward fastest answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62795/158100)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be OK?  You do take a chance of attracting downvotes.  I vote on a post based on the state it is in when I see it, and I usually don't come back later to see if the OP fixed his post, because I expect folks to get it right the first time.  But that's just me.